# File "<stdin>", line 1 syntax error python on linux

Tags: python, astropy

I'm trying to install an astro programm, PAHFits, the problem is that when I run it in the pyhton shell, it appears File "", line 1, as in the image
[image]

I know it's not a problem with PAHFit but I don't know how to solve it!

Help :(

I tried to install from the bash and still have problems

Comment: of course, that is not python code, so it will not even compile and raise a SyntaxError. That is a shell command

Comment: It's a git repo not python file

Comment: You are trying to run a shell command in python Exit python `exit()`, which if you are on the command line gets you back to the shell. Then try that command.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can install libraries either like this:
`pip install git+https://github.com/gretelai/gretel-python-client@main`

or like this:
`python -m pip install git+https://github.com/gretelai/gretel-python-client@main`